# Communication between MS Office Add-ins and another application on MacOS

Tags: macos, office-addins

On MacOS system, I want to achieve below operations,

1. I want to establish a communication between my MS Office Add-In (button added on Ribbon using manifest.xml, click event captured using JavaScript) and my another application (developed in Obj-C).
2. I want to transfer data from Office application(Word/Excel) using my Office Add-in to my Obj-C application, perform some proprietary operation on that data and finally want to transfer modified data back to Office application(Word/Excel).

Can anyone please let me know how can I achieve this?

Thanks,
Amar

Answer (score 2):

Your Office Add-In can make HTTP calls to an external domain in JavaScript. My suggestion:

1. Have your Objective C application run a local web server (something like [CocoaHTTPServer](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaHTTPServer) or [GCDWebServer](https://github.com/swisspol/GCDWebServer)).
2. Add the localhost or 127.0.0.1 domain to the manifest (via [AppDomains](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/manifest/appdomains)).
3. In your add-in code, fetch the data and use either XMLHTTP or Fetch (in my add-ins, I just use jQuery and $.ajax) to send the data to the local app and receive the response.

Note that the use of a web server in your Objective C application may cause additional complications if you are distributing the application via the app store, and there are additional security implications attached to running a service that can be sent arbitrary data.